# Live SDK Applicaition - Unable to Complete Request?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, microsoft-graph-api, azure-api-apps, live-sdk

I have my website integrated with Live SDK applications to allow customers to login to their MSN, Hotmail, Outlook, etc. email accounts and invite friends to my website by reading the contacts.  This used to work properly but now it's not working anymore.

When I use the **App ID / Client ID** from the old **Application Registration Portal (https://apps.dev.microsoft.com)** I get the following message when I try to login using my Microsoft account.

> **invalid_request:** The provided value for the input parameter 'redirect_uri' is not valid. The expected value is a URI which matches a redirect URI registered for this client application.

I see from the **Application Registration Portal** that I can now use **Azure** to manage my **App Registrations**, so I basically setup the same app under **Azure** with the following criteria.

- **Authentication:** Selected **Web** and setup the same **Redirect URI** I was using previously when this was working.
- **API Permissions:** I added "**Microsoft Graph**" with **email**, **Contacts.Read**, **openid**, **profile**, and **User.Read**.

And when I try to login to my Microsoft account using my **Azure** app **Client ID / App ID** I get the following message.

> **unauthorized_client:** The client does not exist or is not enabled for consumers. If you are the application developer, configure a new application through the App Registrations in the Azure Portal at https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2083908.

Should I try making this work using **Azure** instead of **Application Registration Portal** credentials?  If so, why is it saying "**unauthorized_client**" when I try to login?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you still looking for any help on this question

Comment: Yes, I'm still not able to get this to work properly; should I be using "Azure" setup for this now instead of "Application Registration Portal"?  You can see what my URL shows for each in my comment below.  Is there a dedicated MSFT support email for questions about getting this working properly? Ty.

Comment: please use the Azure portal for app registration and the login URL should be as suggested by @allen wu `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=clientid&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost/&response_mode=query&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&state=12345`

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity Ok, I did do the app registration on the Azure portal.  However, regarding the login URL, doesn't Microsoft generate this URL automatically?  Or where can I get more information on having my developer use the right login URL? Because when I do app registration on Azure the login URL that gets automatically generated is what I wrote below in my **Azure client ID credentials** comment.  The login URL doesn't match to the one Allen Wu wrote.

Comment: Mine doesn't show like this "**`https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?`**", it comes up like "**`https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?`**"

Am I using the wrong API code for the login URL?

Answer (score 1):

Register your Azure AD app as **Accounts in any organizational directory (Any Azure AD directory - Multitenant) and personal Microsoft accounts (e.g. Skype, Xbox)**.

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's the selection I made when I registered my app under Azure.  Is there anything else I can try doing to resolve this issue? Ty.

Comment: @olimits7 Please share the login url when you try to login to your Microsoft account. It is like this format: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=cxxxxx6e30bd495ca147c04a4fxxxxx4&response_type=code&redirect_uri=https://localhost/&response_mode=query&scope=openid%20offline_access%20https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2F.default&state=12345`

Comment: This is what it shows when I'm using my new updated **Azure client ID credentials**, which gives me the "**unauthorized_client**" error:  `https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=f1f1550e-5188-419b-b08b-fbf5ebb040ac&scope=openid+https%3a%2f%2foutlook.office.com%2fcontacts.read&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fdomain-name.com%2fen%2ffriends%2fauth%2fhotmail&response_type=code&uaid=743d6b1bedf84047b04a333facf041dd&msproxy=1&issuer=mso&tenant=common&ui_locales=en-US&username=johnsmith%40gmail.com`

Comment: And this is what it shows when I use my old **Application Registration Portal client ID credentials** that give me the "**invalid_request**" error: `https://login.live.com/oauth20_authorize.srf?client_id=0000000048115736&scope=openid+https%3a%2f%2foutlook.office.com%2fcontacts.read&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fdomain-name.com%2fen%2ffriends%2fauth%2fhotmail&response_type=code&uaid=53b6b82491544b4e80a57f2c412fc639&msproxy=1&issuer=mso&tenant=common&ui_locales=en-US&username=johnsmith%40gmail.com`